# System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Tags: c#, linq

This error is happening in many of the files in my "Views" folder:

> 'System.Collection.GenericList' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Select' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.GenericList' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried adding a bunch of "using System..." and other basic libraries near the top of the file but adding those do not seem to help any.

This is where the error occurs for me is in the line that starts with `.BindTo(Model.Users.Select(o => o.UserName))`:

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
 <div id="editRolesContainer" class="detailContainer detailContainer4">
    <header class="sectionheader"> Add Roles </header>
    <ul id = "AdminSelectUserContainer" >
       <li>
          <ul style="padding: 0 0 0 5px">
             <li>Select User : </li>
             <li>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("srch_GetUserRoles", "Admin",
                   new { view = "Users_Roles" }, FormMethod.Post,
                   new { name = "srch_GetUserRoles" }))
                {
                   @(Html.Telerik().AutoComplete()
                          .Name("acx_SelectUser")
                          .BindTo(Model.Users.Select(o => o.UserName))
                              .HtmlAttributes(new { type "submit"   })
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "SearchBox"})
                          .AutoFill(true)
                          .Filterable((filtering =>
                              {
                                 filtering.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains);
                              }))
                  )
                }
             </li>
            </ul>
           ...
           ...
           </div>
```

Comment: Using `System.Linq` would give you access to `Select`

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq`;

Comment: sounds like you're missing a `using System.Linq`

Comment: What type is `Model.Users`? I was getting this when I had a typo and was trying to use .Where on a property that was not enumerable.

Answer (score 201):

Just add this namespace,

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Since it's Razor, the syntax is more likely to be `@using System.Linq`, or you can chuck it in the web.config inside of the View's folder.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about that solution from other people's similar issues. The problem I have though is that even when I do add those changes, the error still exists. I have even tried to manually add the reference by adding the DLL myself, and that doesn't seem to help much either. Starting to think that perhaps a few of my assemblies have mismatched versions?

If so, does anyone have any ideas about how to fix that?

Answer (score 38):

You need to have the `System.Linq` namespace included in your view since Select is an extension method. You have a couple of options on how to do this:

Add `@using System.Linq` to the top of your cshtml file.

If you find that you will be using this namespace often in many of your views, you can do this for *all* views by modifying the web.config inside of your Views folder (not the one at the root). You should see a pages/namespace XML element, create a new `add` child that adds System.Linq. Here is an example:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Linq" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've done all the above, and for some reason it is telling me that:
"The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". 

I can't seem to find this reference anytime I try to add a new one in the "References" sub-folder though.

Comment: I've modified the web-config by manually adding "System.Linq" like you've described above too. So I'm not sure why it is doing this because it doesn't seem like it should be.

Comment: Seems like you need to add a reference to System.Core.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue , When calling Generic.List like:

```
mylist.Select( selectFunc )
```

Where selectFunc is defined as `Expression<Func<T, List<string>>>`. Simply changed "mylist" to be a `IQuerable` instead of `List` then it allowed me to use `.Select`.

Answer (score 4):

This question's bit old, but, there's a tricky scenario which also leads to this error:

In controller:

```
ViewBag.id = //id from querystring
List<string> = GrabDataFromDBByID(ViewBag.id).Select(a=>a.ToString());
```

The above code will lead to an error in this part: `.Select(a=>a.ToString())` because of the below reason:
You're passing a `ViewBag.id` to a method which in compiler, it doesn't know the type, so there might be several methods with the same name and different parameters let's say:

```
GrabDataFromDBByID(string)
GrabDataFromDBByID(int)
GrabDataFromDBByID(whateverType)
```

So to prevent this case, either explicitly cast the ViewBag or create another variable storing it.